# How to print temperature on nextion screen

Tags: raspbian, python, sensor

I am new to the topic of raspberry and sensors, I am doing a project with a raspberry pi 4 and a temperature sensor DS18B20, I created a small project in python to display the temperature in real time.

```
import time
from w1thermsensor import W1ThermSensor
sensor = W1ThermSensor()

while True:
      temperature = sensor.get_temperature()
      print("The temperature is %s celsius" % temperature)
      time.sleep(1)
```

Now what I need is to display the temperature on a nextion screen, I already loaded the interface to the screen, I created a variable called "celcius.val". but I don't know how to get the temperature from the sensor and print it in the variable.

[image]

Comment: I have never heard of a nextion screen or the interface to the nextion screen.  This seems to be a general programming question, not specific to the Pi.

Comment: definitely not about Raspberry Pi ... nexion screen is irrelevant ... the actual question is `how to send serial data from Python?`

Comment: yes please, I am new at this

Answer (score 1):

Since Nextion instruction sets are [sent over serial](https://nextion.tech/2017/12/08/nextion-hmi-upload-protocol-v1-1/), you would need to:

1. Connect your Pi to the Nextion screen through [serial.](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-serial/)
2. Connect to the screen in [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59212853/connecting-rs232-to-serial-and-establishing-a-connection-to-nextion-display-from).
3. [Assign](https://nextion.tech/instruction-set/#s2) your temperature reading to your variable:

```py
command = "celcius.val=" + temperature
ser.write(command.encode('utf-8'))
```